# Visual Studio 2013 C++ - guidelines

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

Few years back I've used Dev C++, just recently while working on some projects I remembered one its feature I miss a lot.

My English is not so great, so probably the word I've used isn't exactly right, but here is the picture.
[image: Dev C++]

See that lines by if/for/while/..., that identify exactly where it begins and where it ends.

Is it possible to add something like this is Visual Studio 2013?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, via extensions. There's several: [Indent Guides](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&sqi=2&ved=0CCUQFjAA&url=http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/e792686d-542b-474a-8c55-630980e72c30&ei=jRUnU5ngGPLV4ASmt4HgDA&usg=AFQjCNEEJWCdnS1sxK3RfSxMF46SVBTCfg&sig2=DpeqfkB55EEpfa5dR_2NeQ) and [Productivity Power Tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/d0d33361-18e2-46c0-8ff2-4adea1e34fef) for example. The latter provides a lot of [useful?] modifications.

Comment: Thank You very much, I will use Indent Guides from now on.

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio allows you to

- automatically format the code with indentation adjustment (Edit > Avanced > Format Selection)
- collapse/expand blocks (Edit > Outlining > ...)

Comment: I'm familiar with it, and I alredy use it